# How to add Academy module on odoo 8.0 on windows?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

Cannot find Academy module in odoo 8.0 , trying to add it in the modules via "./odoo.py scaffold Academy my-modules" and "./odoo.py --addons-path addons,my-modules" commands on command prompt but its not getting added. Please can anyone guide me on how to add it?

Comment: Do you want to create a new module named 'academy'  or want to use the odoo academy module available in odoo apps?

Comment: i want to use the odoo academy module available in odoo apps,, but i cant find it i am following https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/howtos/website.html ,,, in order to create a website but unable to do it.I am new to odoo and i have just installed it.

Comment: The academy module is only available for Odoo 6.1 version.
https://apps.openerp.com/apps?search=academy

Comment: thanku so much sir! actually i need to create a website like literally code it , but since I am new to odoo cant figure out how to do it.  please help.

Comment: Would it be better to use odoo 6.0 instead of odoo 8.0?
Does odoo 6.0 have it  all configured in order to develop a website i mean like the Academy module.
which one would be more easier for website development